# How can I make a table on rmarkdown more compact?

Tags: html, r, dataframe, r-markdown

I used a dataframe on rmarkdown, but when I knit to html it is too large and uses a lot of space. Is
there any way to make it more compact?

[image: code and the print of the data frame. It's uncomfortable to see because there are more rows but you can't see them at once since each of them uses a lot of space]

I've tried looking around in the DT instructions but haven't found any options to change that.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the vertical spaces using the `lineHeight` property:

```
formatStyle(columns = 1:5, lineHeight='30%')
```